# Saga messaging implementation with RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq, saga

I'm new to RabbitMQ and want to implement asynchronous messaging of SAGA with RabbitMQ.So I used RPC example of RabbitMQ to do the task. I've one orchestrator ( RPCClient)  and multiple microservices ( RPCServer).  Orchestrator uses unique queues to command microservices.And each microservice uses a common queue ( Reply_ Queue) to reply orchestrator. To keep log I want to get notifications in orchestrator side, when any microservice is down for any configurable time.
I read about consumer cancellation,but it only works when I delete the queue.How to get notifications in JAVA with keeping queue messages?  And is it correct way to implement saga asynchronous messaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a reliable RPC is hard, I can't give a detail guide about how to do this. If we ignore same special failure situation, I can give a simple workaround:

First, we assume that `RPCClient` never fail, `RPCServer` may fail anytime.

`RPCClient` need to know which request is timeout, so it can send `request message` with a [TTL](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html). After `RPCServer` receive `request message` and send `response message`, it should `ACK` the `request message`.

If `RPCServer`:

- has failed before consume `request message` 
  *OR*
- has failed before send `response message`

The `request message` will be republish to [Dead Letter Exchange](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html), so `RPCClient` can consume to some queue binded with that exchange, it can know which request is timeout.